# Japanese word using で” in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-で

芸達者で食欲が旺盛な、ごくふつうの犬です。

I'm currently reading a short manga and this sentence was used at the end of the chapter, for context the story is about a タヌキ (usually referred as a dog).

That one day the owner's dad goes to see the new dog, and he sees that this new "Dog" is capable of writing in a flipbook, so he got shooked. The owner tells her dad that he is like those dogs that are on the tv that are *performers*.

At the end of the chapter, there's an extra "narrator-like" phrase that says:

> "芸達者で食欲が旺盛な、ごくふつうの犬です。"

I interpret it as two different phrases that complement, the first part says "芸達者**で**食欲が旺盛な" wich the で I see at the "place" where the rest occurs, something like "*Being clever makes her hungry*" then the phrase is complemented by the rest "ごくふつうの犬です" which is something like "That's how dog usually be".

The use of the で as a "referring place" of the action is correct? or should I see as a whole text that refers to the clever/good-at-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The で here doesn't refer to location in this context. This で is used to link 形容動詞/na-adjectives. It lets multiple adjectives describe a noun in one sentence.

彼女はしとやか**で**奇麗な女の子です。
She is a refined, beautiful girl.

芸達者**で**食欲が旺盛な、ごくふつうの犬です。
A good at performing, big-appetited, extremely normal dog. (literal translation) 
An extremely normal dog that just happens to be good at performing and has a big appetite. (more natural translation)